# Application freezes after few hours of playback

Tags: android, freeze, exoplayer

Have developed application with ExoPlayer. Which works fine for shorter period. After few hours of continuous playback, app freezes. Not even the back button. Don't see any logs after the freeze in the logcat of androidStudio.

I used android profiler to check with the memory. I can see native memory is increasing. The app size is 45MB. Native memory increased from 120MB to 390MB. I don't know where does this memory is keep on adding.

There is only one activity and a fragment is there in my app. Live content will be playing on start.

Don't know how to fix this. Not even the logs are helping. Sometimes app crashes. But I don't see any logs.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm also using ExoPlayer and am curious about the problem. Some more info might be useful. Are you playing audio? Video? What format? Is the behavior consistent across multiple media items? What about different devices and emulators? Are you looping? If so, how long is the media item itself? Have you put a listener on the player that logs all relevant events (especially errors)? If possible, have you tried playing the same media with MediaPlayer or some other alternative? And so on. If you could update your post with some more details, it might help.

Comment: @scg I am playing video. I am checking this with the real TV devices. I am playing  m3u8. I have added the logs. Once the app freezes, there are no logs are logged in the logcat.

Comment: Not sure, but you could try [posting an issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues). If you don't get any answers here, you might be able to get some help there.

Comment: Any help on why native memory is increasing? How to resolve this?